# Change Title header of AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I am trying to change the title header of Alertdialog box but the output is not what I exactly wanted. I am creating the following style in styles.xml:

```
<style name="question_dialog" 
  parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/question_dialog_title</item>
</style>

<style name="question_dialog_title" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
<item name="android:background">#5cc5cc</item>
<item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

The java code is as follows :

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this, 
R.style.question_dialog).setTitle("Assam Quiz" ). 
setMessage("Hello world Hello world"). 
setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) - > 
{dialog.dismisd();
}).show();
}
```

The AlertDialog image is attached. [image]

Comment: Your style creating problem in this case. Try with different style

Comment: Do you want to hide Actionbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

out of the style - *I think your dialog has some header layout set to it that prevents the title to be at the top, but if that is the case or not* - you can easily [set a custom title](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setCustomTitle(android.view.View)) for the dialog header giving it the header layout only, and so you will have the full control for the dialog header:

```
// creating the Dialog
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
// getting dialog context
Context mContext = builder.getContext();
// building the inflater
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
// inflate the dialog header layout
View mView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_dialog_header, null);
// get the TextView for the header (contained in the header layout)
TextView mTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
// set the text for that TextView
mTextView.setText(message);
// set the custom header view for the dialog
builder.setCustomTitle(mView);
/*
here you can set positive , negative ,neutral buttons
or set the dialog message or any attribute you want
*/
// finally, show the dialog
builder.show();
```

and for the header layout (`R.layout.simple_dialog_header`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/primary"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you are welcome, glad you have your problem solved :)